# aws cli and jq - return objects where attributes match patterns

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jq

I have more than 100 Auto Scaling Groups.

I'd like to be able to search my Auto Scaling groups based on a regex of the AutoScalingGroupName and return the AutoScalingGroupARN(s) (if exists).

So far I have:

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups | jq '.AutoScalingGroups[].AutoScalingGroupName | capture("(?<result>my-regex-pattern)")'
```

While this does return the AutoScalingGroupNames, I'd like to also return the AutoScalingGroupARN rather than do another command using the output from the previous command.

So given the following output from `aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups`:

```
{
    "AutoScalingGroups": [
        {
            "AutoScalingGroupARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:123456789012:autoScalingGroup:208e9fe9-3a9b-4f30-9b47-855f4a7ee671:autoScalingGroupName/abc-app-dev-as-1IZQABPFDAV2A",
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "abc-app-dev-as-1IZQABPFDAV2A",
            "...": "more output"
        },
        {
            "AutoScalingGroupARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:123456789012:autoScalingGroup:c6463f9a-7fa1-41de-a39b-7996d2b8cbb1:autoScalingGroupName/foo-app-dev-as-1IZQABPFDAV2A",
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "foo-app-dev-as-1IZQABPFDAV2A",
            "...": "more output"
        }
        {
            "AutoScalingGroupARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:123456789012:autoScalingGroup:6a659b27-1ea7-4d39-8a8b-790153033b39:autoScalingGroupName/abc-app-prod-as-1IZQABPFDAV2A",
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "abc-app-prod-as-1IZQABPFDAV2A",
            "...": "more output"
        },
        {
            "Lots more": "Like the above"
        }
    ]
}
```

And am only interested in `AutoScalingGroupName` matching `/abc-app.+/`, I'd want the output of:

```
{
    "results": [
         {
            "AutoScalingGroupARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:123456789012:autoScalingGroup:208e9fe9-3a9b-4f30-9b47-855f4a7ee671:autoScalingGroupName/abc-app-dev-as-1IZQABPFDAV2A",
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "abc-app-dev-as-1IZQABPFDAV2A"
        },
        {
            "AutoScalingGroupARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:123456789012:autoScalingGroup:6a659b27-1ea7-4d39-8a8b-790153033b39:autoScalingGroupName/abc-app-prod-as-1IZQABPFDAV2A",
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "abc-app-prod-as-1IZQABPFDAV2A"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A minimal example of the JSON would be helpful. See the guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry for the lack of context. Thanks for checking the AWS docs to see the standard output for that command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a "select" query along the following lines:

```
.AutoScalingGroups[]
| select(.AutoScalingGroupName | test("group"))
| .AutoScalingGroupARN
```

Given the example aws output at
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-groups.html

the above filter produces:

```
"arn:aws:autoscaling:us-west-2:123456789012:autoScalingGroup:930d940e-891e-4781-a11a-7b0acd480f03:autoScalingGroupName/my-auto-scaling-group"
```

If you want both the Name and ARN, then just grab them both, e.g.:

```
.AutoScalingGroups[]
 | select(.AutoScalingGroupName | test("group"))
 | {AutoScalingGroupName, AutoScalingGroupARN}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!!